# In IE 8/9 - cant click image, inside anchor that is wrapped with span using display:block

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a bit of a problem creating a navigation element - its working fine in firefox, but seems to be causing me a headache in IE8/IE9. The other odd thing is that it works fine in IE on when running under localhost, but not when run on a server.

I've tried to narrow down the actual issue, and its seems to be caused by me wrapping a couple of elements (an img and some text), in a span that has display:block. When I do this the image no longer responds to the href javascript of the anchor tag. Its kind of difficult to explain so I've included a cut down example:

```
<a title="My Link" href='javascript:alert(1);' style="display: block; height: 37px; text-decoration: none;">
    <span style="display: block; height: 34px;">
        <img title="My Icon" src="mypic.png" alt="ss" />
        <span>Link Text</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Any help would be great!

Matt

Comment: I don't have a problem while testing your code, i guess you used floating on one of the elements?

Comment: In my actual project the image is floated, but I'm reproducing this issue without anything being floated. With the exact code above, I cannot click on the image in IE - if I run it from the file system or localhost it works just fine, but if I run it on a server I cannot click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other odd thing is that it works fine in IE on when running under
>   localhost, but not when run on a server.

In that case, the problem is to do with the rendering mode that IE is using. Hit F12 to bring up the Developer Tools to see which mode is being used.

Adding this to your `<head>` should sort the problem out:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Brilliant - that sorted it! As you mentioned, it wasn't working with IE compatibility mode. Thankyou!!

Comment: Well this will actually just force users to use the latest version of IE. So if they visit in an older browser the problem persists.

Comment: @bsthomsen: True, but OP wanted to know why this problem was happening in *IE8/9*. Evidently, he didn't care about ancient versions such as IE7.